# How to test login with Bcrypt in Express with Mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, bcrypt, supertest

I have implemented a login with hashed password authentication via Bcrypt in my Express Backend. Registration and login, as well as authenticated routes, work fine in the app, but not in the test environment. The following registration test succeeds, but the login test fails. When I log the password inside the user model's compare function, it is logged as plain text instead of the hash. I don't understand why though.

Any help is appreciated.

This is the users.test.js:

```
import { expect, server, BASE_URL } from './setup'

describe('User', () => {
  it('registers a user', (done) => {
    const data = { email: 'chester@benning.ton', name: 'chester', password: 'intheend' }
    server
      .post(`${BASE_URL}/users`)
      .send(data)
      .expect(201)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.equal(201)
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('user')
        expect(res.body.user).to.have.property('id')
        expect(res.body.user).to.have.property('name', data.name)
        done()
      })
  })

  it('logs in a user', (done) => {
    const data = { name: 'chester', password: 'intheend' }
    server
      .post(`${BASE_URL}/users/login`)
      .send(data)
      .expect(201)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.equal(201)
        expect(res.body.user).to.have.property('id')
        done()
      })
  })
})
```

The user model looks like this:

```
const { Model, Op } = require('sequelize')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const config = require('../../config/config')

function hashPassword(user) {
  const saltRounds = config.saltRounds

  if (!user.changed('password')) {
    return false
  }

  return bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds).then((hashedPassword) => {
    user.setDataValue('password', hashedPassword)
  })
}

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {}

  User.init({
    email: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isUnique(value, next) {
          User.findOne({
            where: {
              email: {
                [Op.iLike]: value.trim()
              }
            }
          }).then((user) => {
            if (user) {
              return next('E-Mail is already registered')
            }
            return next()
          }).catch(() => next('Could not be validated'))
        }
      }
    },
    name: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isUnique(value, next) {
          User.findOne({
            where: {
              name: {
                [Op.iLike]: value.trim()
              }
            }
          }).then((user) => {
            if (user) {
              return next('User name already exists')
            }
            return next()
          }).catch(() => next('Could not be validated'))
        }
      }
    },
    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: hashPassword,
      beforeSave: hashPassword,
      beforeUpdate: hashPassword
    },
    modelName: 'User',
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'Users'
  })

  User.prototype.comparePassword = async function comparePassword(password) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password).then((res) => {
      return res
    }).catch((err) => {
      return false
    })
  }

  User.prototype.toJSON = function toJSON() {
    const userObj = { ...this.get() }
    delete userObj.password
    return userObj
  }

  return User
}
```

And this is my UserController.js:

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { User } = require('../models')
const config = require('../../config/config')

function jwtSignUser(user) {
  const ONE_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24
  return jwt.sign(user, config.authentication.jwtSecret, {
    expiresIn: ONE_DAY
  })
}

module.exports = {
  findAll(req, res) {
    const options = {
      attributes: {
        exclude: [ 'password' ]
      },
      order: [
        [ 'name', 'ASC' ]
      ]
    }
    return User.findAll(options).then((users) => res.status(200).send(users)).catch(() => {
      res.status(404).send({
        message: 'Could not find users'
      })
    })
  },

  login(req, res) {
    const { name, password } = req.body

    User.findOne({
      where: {
        name: {
          [Op.iLike]: name
        }
      }
    }).then(async (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          message: 'Login information incorrect'
        })
      }

      const passwordIsValid = await user.comparePassword(password)

      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          message: 'Login information incorrect'
        })
      }

      const userJson = user.toJSON()

      return res.status(201).send({
        user: userJson,
        token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
    }).catch(() => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: 'Login was not successful'
      })
    })
  },

  register(req, res) {
    return User.create(req.body).then((user) => {
      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      return res.status(201).send({
        user: userJson,
        token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(422).send({
        message: error.errors[0].message
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to say based on what you've posted, but it is generally regarded as extremely problematic for tests to depend on other tests. Your tests should be completely atomic, and the ordering of the tests should not matter. Having one test create a user, and then a second different test assume the first test has already run is a bad idea, and most frameworks will not allow this to happen, typically providing some mechanism to isolate tests from each other's data (for example, database transactions).

Comment: If you want to test that a login works, you have to create the associated data **in that test**, not in some prior test. Typically you do this through some kind of factory/fixture API.

Comment: I hear you. I finally fixed it. First of all, the problem was in the User model. It hashed the password (at least) twice because of all the hooks that ran `hasPassword`. Second of all I now use a JSON file in my fixtures folder to create users in the test's `before()` hook, one of which I log in later on. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It works and feels super clean now.